# How do you create a keystore given csr, key, pem and crt

Tags: ssl, ssl-certificate, keystore, centos7

This is a little bit of an unusual situation. I have a CentOS 7 server running tomcat 7 and I need to install a new SSL cert for it. I don't have control over the domain so the cert generated for me was given to me by the parent company and it's for a start cert (*.domain.com). Even though I sent them a csr, they ignored it and made a new one for me. The package they sent has a csr file, key, two formats of the cert (crt and p7s), and an intermediary pem.

I'm trying to create a new keystore using these files and am having difficulty doing it. I found this site https://makandracards.com/jan0sch/24553-import-private-key-and-certificate-into-java-keystore and have tried:

```
openssl pkcs12 -export -in my.crt -inkey my.key -chain -CAfile my-ca-file.crt -name "my-domain.com" -out my.p12
```

I changed the CAfile to use the pem file supplied, but I get "unable to load certificates"

Anyone have any ideas?

EDIT:

I used this to make the p12 and then import it in the keystore but I don't know how to include the intermediate cert.

```
openssl pkcs12 -export -in my.crt -inkey myh.key -certfile my.crt -name "tomcat" -out keystore.p12
keytool -importkeystore -srckeystore keystore.p12 -srcstoretype pkcs12 -destkeystore keystore -deststoretype JKS
```

EDIT2:

I'm trying this command to get a pfx file and then

EDIT3:
My intermediate cert had a bunch of spaces preceding the "-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----" which was causing an error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like all I had to do was this:

```
openssl pkcs12 -export -in my.crt -inkey myh.key -certfile intermediary.pem -name "tomcat" -out keystore.p12

keytool -importkeystore -srckeystore keystore.p12 -srcstoretype pkcs12 -destkeystore keystore -deststoretype JKS
```

Didn't even need to put in the intermediate cert.